# How do I have a changing, but known number in a hyperlink?

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I am new to using sheets or excel. I would like to be able to create a hyperlink that I can control some of the characters within the link and have them auto-fill based on what row the link is in.

It seems that putting more " around the characters I want to control does something, but always ends up making the cell display ERROR.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://scryfall.com/card/war/1", $A$2)
```

I would like the "1" to be 2-1, but then be able to apply that to many different rows. For example, if it was row 30, it would be 30-1.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vcSHLDkM1YyQwvNXEGjB2GamPnqVf9QMLfHb-RFuZ9E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to process 100 rows, you could try (in row 2)

```
=ArrayFormula(HYPERLINK("https://scryfall.com/card/war/"&row(A2:A100)&"-1"; A$2:A100))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: This works. Although I have to have the friendly names somewhere on the sheet, I can type those out and then hide the column. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), 
 HYPERLINK("https://scryfall.com/card/war/"&(ROW(A1:A)), K2:K), ))
```

[image: 0]

and in **B2** you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), ROW(A1:A), ))
```

[image: 0]

if you want to append **`-1`** to each URL do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), 
 HYPERLINK("https://scryfall.com/card/war/"&(ROW(A1:A)&"-1"), K2:K), ))
```

[image: 0]